# Excluding numbered-index elements of PDO::fetchAll()

Tags: php, json, pdo

*`$allrows = $pdo->fetchAll(); // select * from ....`*

I want to transform this *`$allrows`* into JSON by doing :

*`echo (json_encode($allrowl,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));`*

My problem is that this *`fetchAll`* will not only extracting data as *associate array* but also *indexed array* for each element,  hence repeating elements.

```
[
    {
        "org_id": "1",
        "0": "1",
        "category": "A",
        "1": "A",

    },
    {
        "org_id": "2",
        "0": "2",
        "category": "A",
        "1": "A",

    }
]
```

Thank you.

Comment: you need [`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_ASSOC) mode. it can be set either as a PDOStatement::fetchAll() parameter or as a default mode once for all, as a connect option, wich is very convenient.

Comment: Men, thank you so much, what wasted hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's becuase the default fetch mode is `FETCH_BOTH`.  CHange your mode to `FETCH_ASSOC` and you'll only get the non-numeric keys.

Assuming `$pdo` is a `PDOStatement`, set it like this prior to the fetch.

```
   $pdo->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can also set it in the fetch statement:

```
   $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: woah thank you Ray, I've doing a lot of looping manipulation just to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to get only the associated arrays:

```
$allrows = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: woah thank you aynber, I've doing a lot of looping manipulation just to achieve this, @Ray answered first but I gave you upvote.

Comment: there is no fetchAll() method in PDO class. thus, most likely this code won't work

Comment: @YourCommonSense http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php  assuming the `$pdo` variable is a `PDOStatement`

Comment: @YourCommonSense Check the link I posted. It's the PDO fetchAll() method. Therefore, it exists.

Comment: "Controls the contents of the returned array as documented in PDOStatement::fetch(). Defaults to value of PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE (which defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH)"  `fetch()` is where FETCH_ASSOC is documented.